# Reponsive JQuery Mobile Grid

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am having difficulties creating a responsive grid with jQuery mobile and CSS3 media query. I do have it responding, but it doesn't rearrange the way I would like. Here is what I have.

It is a 2 row by 5 column grid.
I am trying to turn it into a 10 row by single column. This I can do, but I am trying to get the order the way I want it.

So it looks like this

```
|A|B|C|D|E|

|A|B|C|D|E|
```

I am trying to get it to do this below (I want it AABBCCDDEE but I can only manage it going down in ABCDEABCDE order...)

---

### |A|

### |A|

### |B|

### |B|

### |C|

### |C|

### |D|

### |D|

### |E|

### |E|

Here is my code for the grid:

```
<div class="ui-grid-d my-breakpoint">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <input type="image" id="jog" src="images/jog.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <input type="image" id="rewfwd" src="images/rewfwdOff.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <input type="image" id="hand" src="images/handOff.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        <input type="image" id="auto" src="images/autoOff.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-e">
        <input type="image" id="off" src="images/offOff.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#jogPopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button"  data-theme="a" data-icon="gear" data-position-to="header">Jog</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#rewfwdPopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="gear" data-position-to="header" data-transition="slideup">R F</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <a href="#handPopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="gear" data-position-to="header" data-transition="slideup">Hand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        <a href="#autoPopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="gear" data-position-to="header" data-transition="slideup">Auto</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-e">
        <a href="#offPopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="gear" data-position-to="header" data-transition="slideup">Off</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this isn't the right CSS to get this to work, I've tried a few different things but here is the standard responsive CSS

```
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
.my-breakpoint .ui-block-a, 
.my-breakpoint .ui-block-b, 
.my-breakpoint .ui-block-c,
.my-breakpoint .ui-block-d,
.my-breakpoint .ui-block-e { 
    width: 100%; 
    float:none; 
 }
}
```

Anybody have any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to rearrange the flow position of those divs, you are either going to have to absolutely position them where you want them [with CSS], or physically move the nodes where you want them [with JS].

A third solution, you could rearrange your initial html/css to something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-grid-d my-breakpoint">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <input type="image" id="jog" src="images/jog.gif">
        <a href="#jogPopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button"  data-theme="a" data-icon="gear" data-position-to="header">Jog</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-breakpoint .ui-block-a a {
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

Essentially, this would give you the effect of the two stacked rows for your "non-collapsed" view. Then, within your media query, you could set all `A` and `INPUT` elements to `display:block` to have them form one stacked column (and they would naturally stack the way you want).

I fiddle, with this idea a little more flushed out: http://jsfiddle.net/BddhH/

Comment: Thanks Bart! Plan 3 it is!

Comment: I added a fiddle that flushes this idea out a little more.

Answer (score -1):

SIMPLE SOLUTION TO MOBILE GRID

JUST EXTEND THE BOOTSTRAP GRID - LIKE THIS

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 766px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .mob-xs-1, .mob-sm-1, .mob-xs-2, .mob-sm-2, .mob-xs-3, .mob-sm-3, .mob-xs-4, .mob-sm-4, .mob-xs-5, .mob-sm-5, .mob-xs-6, .mob-sm-6, .mob-xs-7, .mob-sm-7, .mob-xs-8, .mob-sm-8, .mob-xs-9, .mob-sm-9, .mob-xs-10, .mob-sm-10, .mob-xs-11, .mob-sm-11, .mob-xs-12, .mob-sm-12 {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-left: 2px;
    }


    .container-fluid {
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .row {
        margin-right: -2px;
        margin-left: -2px;
    }
}



.mob-xs-1, .mob-xs-2, .mob-xs-3, .mob-xs-4, .mob-xs-5, .mob-xs-6, .mob-xs-7, .mob-xs-8, .mob-xs-9, .mob-xs-10, .mob-xs-11, .mob-xs-12 {
    float: left;
}

.mob-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.mob-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.mob-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.mob-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.mob-xs-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
}

.mob-xs-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
}

.mob-xs-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
}

.mob-xs-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
}

.mob-xs-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
}

.mob-xs-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-push-0 {
    left: auto;
}

.mob-xs-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}

.mob-xs-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mob-sm-1, .mob-sm-2, .mob-sm-3, .mob-sm-4, .mob-sm-5, .mob-sm-6, .mob-sm-7, .mob-sm-8, .mob-sm-9, .mob-sm-10, .mob-sm-11, .mob-sm-12 {
        float: left;
    }

    .mob-sm-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mob-sm-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .mob-sm-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .mob-sm-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .mob-sm-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-12 {
        right: 100%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-9 {
        right: 75%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-7 {
        right: 58.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-6 {
        right: 50%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-3 {
        right: 25%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-2 {
        right: 16.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-1 {
        right: 8.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-pull-0 {
        right: auto;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-12 {
        left: 100%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-11 {
        left: 91.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-10 {
        left: 83.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-9 {
        left: 75%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-7 {
        left: 58.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-6 {
        left: 50%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-3 {
        left: 25%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-2 {
        left: 16.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-1 {
        left: 8.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-push-0 {
        left: auto;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-12 {
        margin-left: 100%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333333%;
    }

    .mob-sm-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}


@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

.visible-xs,
.visible-sm {
    display: none !important;
}

.visible-xs-block,
.visible-xs-inline,
.visible-xs-inline-block,
.visible-sm-block,
.visible-sm-inline,
.visible-sm-inline-block {
    display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    table.visible-xs {
        display: table !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xs,
    td.visible-xs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs-inline {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs-inline-block {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .visible-sm {
        display: block !important;
    }

    table.visible-sm {
        display: table !important;
    }

    tr.visible-sm {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-sm,
    td.visible-sm {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .visible-sm-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .visible-sm-inline {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}


@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .hidden-xs {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        .hidden-sm {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```